# How to filter grouped data based on a single column values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have large patient dataset with diagnosis information (It has more columns than shown below, which are unnecessary for this). I have generated a sample datset like below:

```
ID      Name    Gender  Diagnosis_Class
ID_100  John    Male    Primary
ID_101  David   Male    Primary
ID_102  Susan   Female  Primary
ID_102  Susan   Female  Related
ID_103  Steve   Male    Primary
ID_103  Steve   Male    Primary
ID_103  Steve   Male    Related
ID_104  Kevin   Male    Primary
ID_104  Kevin   Male    Primary
ID_105  Peter   Male    Related
ID_106  Ben     Male    Primary
ID_107  Sophie  Female  Related
```

As you can see from the dataset from the dataset, some records are duplicated but their **Diagnosis_Class** values are different. Some of them only have **Primary**, some of them only have **Related** diagnosis class information, and some of them have both.

My question is, How can I make sure entries with **Related** Diagnosis_Class also have **Primary** Diagnosis_Class?? For example, **Susan** has both **Primary** and **Related** Diagnosis_Class, so I need to wtite a query to flag these entries with **Related** as values (Can be in another column with YES or NO, or Y or N, etc).

Also I only need only one of each **Diagnosis_Class** type (One entry with Primary and one enrty with Related diagnosis classes) when the entries have multiple **Primary** or **Related** values. For example, Steve has two records with **Primary** diagnosis class and one record with **Related** diagnosis class. I only need two records from those three (One with primary and one with related. Doesn't really matter which primary record is picked). As per records with only Related diagnosis class, the record can be kept as it it.

I am fairly new to **SQL Server (v17.9.1)** world. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks you very much for your time.

---

Thanks for your quick response.

Here's the desired output:

```
ID      Name    Gender  Diagnosis_Class  Flag
ID_100  John    Male    Primary         
ID_101  David   Male    Primary
ID_102  Susan   Female  Primary
ID_102  Susan   Female  Related          Yes
ID_103  Steve   Male    Primary
ID_103  Steve   Male    Related          Yes
ID_104  Kevin   Male    Primary
ID_104  Kevin   Male    Primary
ID_105  Peter   Male    Related          No
ID_106  Ben     Male    Primary
ID_107  Sophie  Female  Related          No
```

As you can see, I have removed following entries:
`ID_103  Steve   Male    Primary` and `ID_103  Steve   Male    Primary` because there's two entries with **Primary** Diagnosis_Class and I only need one **Primary** and one **Related** (which **Primary** we ignore is not important as I am more interested in **Related** whenever an entry has one)

I also flagged all entries with **Related** Diagnosis_Class **Yes** when they have a **Primary** Diagnosis_Class attached to them, and **No** when there's no **Primary** Diagnosis_Class attached to them. We can leave the rest NULL or add 'N/A' or simply leave empty (Not Important).

As per entries with multiple **Primary** Diagnosis_Class but no **Related** Diagnosis_Class, I kept them all as they were.

I hope I am making sense here as I am struggling since it's too complicated for my experience.

Thank you for your time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Are the only possible `Diagnosis_Class` values are `Primary` and `Related`?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of DISTINCT clause to avoid duplicates and for the second part:

> How can I make sure entries with Related Diagnosis_Class also have Primary Diagnosis_Class??

You can use a CASE statement for those rows where Diagnosis_Class = 'Related' that try to find a matching row with Diagnosis_class = 'Primary'.

Assuming your table name is patient:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ID, 
    Name, 
    Gender, 
    Diagnosis_Class,
    CASE WHEN Diagnosis_Class = 'Related' THEN 
        IIF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM patient WHERE ID=p.ID AND Diagnosis_Class='Primary'), 'Yes', 'No')
        ELSE ''
    END AS Flag
FROM 
    patient p;
```

Gives you this result:

| ID | Name | Gender | Diagnosis_Class | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_100 | John | Male | Primary |  |
| ID_101 | David | Male | Primary |  |
| ID_102 | Susan | Female | Primary |  |
| ID_102 | Susan | Female | Related | Yes |
| ID_103 | Steve | Male | Primary |  |
| ID_103 | Steve | Male | Related | Yes |
| ID_104 | Kevin | Male | Primary |  |
| ID_105 | Peter | Male | Related | No |
| ID_106 | Ben | Male | Primary |  |
| ID_107 | Sophie | Female | Related | No |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=34325a74bcbae25564647612a925b52b)*

Comment: This is exactly the output I need and it works perfctly on my dataset. Thanks for your answer McNets.